# Curves creating artifacts?

Tags: bezier-curves, artifacts, curve-modifier

My mesh is issue free when laid flat but when a curve modifier is applied, it gains these artifacts. They do not show up as an edge or at all in edit mode, only in object mode. It's an issue because I want to 3D print it but these artifacts ruin the mesh when imported into 3d printing software.

[image: Clean Mesh]

[[image: Mesh placed on curve with artifacts2]

Comment: The Curve modifier will bend your object, if it has not enough topology to bend, it may have some faces intersecting, etc, or just a topology that you may not want, but please share your file so that we understand better: https://blend-exchange.com/